# Why does hover have a gap when using flex justify-content: space-between?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is how my code looks like. I was using flexbox to fill all the horizontal space in my navigation but when I hover, it just seems to miss this little gap that forced them to fill the whole space.

[image]

```
parent{
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

li{
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ywhmt7c6/12/#&togetherjs=0LhVaVPH68)
You can have a look here

Comment: can you show us your html and hover css

Comment: If you want to be able to directly hover from one item to the next, then you don’t want _space_ between your items, but make your items themselves _grow_ so that there is no more space between them.

Comment: Added the demo link @לבנימלכה

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. enclosed them to 100% wrapper
2. specific width to inner wrapper + overflow: auto; white-space: nowrap;
3. used display:table-cell;

```css
#menu a {
  color: #009fda;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  max-width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#Nav {
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background: #01a182;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #999;
  width: 100% !important;
}

#Nav .inner-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#Nav #menu {
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  display: table;
}

#menu li {
  display: table-cell;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
}

#menu a.Link {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
}

#menu li:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
}

#menu a.Link.active,
#menu a.Link:hover {
  background: #0e6857;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="Nav">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li> <a class="Link" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li> <a class="Link" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li> <a class="Link" href="#">2</a></li>
      <li> <a class="Link" href="#">3</a></li>
      <li> <a class="Link" href="#">4</a></li>
      <li> <a class="Link" href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```